# Problem on adding quantity in existing item in DataGridView - vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, for-loop, if-statement

I am creating a shopping system as my university mini project, where the user can enter the barcode of an item they wanted and the entered item will be added to the grid on the right and also as a new item to the grid on the left. Each item has a unique barcode and can have the same product code. When the user enters an item with the same product code then quantity will be added on the grid on the left. I am having a problem where when the second item quantity need to be added, the system is detecting it as a new item instead of adding the quantity

eg:
[Example of products and items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCGAi.png)

```
    Public Sub addRecordTo2ndDGV()
    Try
        dbconnection()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM items_database WHERE Item_Barcode = @ItemBarcode;"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = sql
            .Parameters.Clear()
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemBarcode", formUser.barcodeTB.Text)
        End With
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter
        dt = New DataTable
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim ItemProductCode, ItemBarcode As String
            Dim repeated As Boolean = False
            ItemProductCode = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
            ItemBarcode = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
            formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text = ItemProductCode
            formUser.itembarcodetb.Text = ItemBarcode
            
            For Each row2 As DataGridViewRow In formUser.ItemBarcodeDGV.Rows
                If Convert.ToString(row2.Cells(1).Value) = formUser.itembarcodetb.Text AndAlso Convert.ToString(row2.Cells(0).Value) = formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text Then
                    MsgBox("QUANTITY WILL MINUS")
                    minusQuantity()
                    formUser.ItemBarcodeDGV.Rows.Remove(row2)
                    MsgBox("QUANTITY HAS MINUS")
                    Exit For

                ElseIf Convert.ToString(row2.Cells(1).Value) <> formUser.itembarcodetb.Text AndAlso Convert.ToString(row2.Cells(0).Value) = formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text Then
                    MsgBox("QUANTITY WILL ADD")
                    formUser.ItemBarcodeDGV.Rows.Add(New String() {formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text, formUser.itembarcodetb.Text})
                    addQuantity()
                    MsgBox("QUANTITY HAS ADDED")
                    Exit For

                ElseIf Convert.ToString(row2.Cells(1).Value) <> formUser.itembarcodetb.Text AndAlso Convert.ToString(row2.Cells(0).Value) <> formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text Then
                    MsgBox("NEW ITEM")
                    formUser.ItemBarcodeDGV.Rows.Add(New String() {formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text, formUser.itembarcodetb.Text})
                    addRecord()
                    MsgBox("REGISTERED SUCCESSFULL")
                    Exit For
                End If
                Exit For
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("Barcode not registered!")
            formUser.barcodeTB.Text = ""
            formUser.barcodeTB.Focus()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        da.Dispose()
        formUser.barcodeTB.Text = ""
        clearUserForm()
        retrieveSubTotal()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub addRecord()
    If formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Scan a barcode")
    Else
        Try
            dbconnection()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM products_database WHERE Product_Code = @ProductCode;"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = sql
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text)
            End With
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter
            dt = New DataTable
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim productcode, itemdescription, unitprice As String
                Dim repeated As Boolean = False
                productcode = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
                itemdescription = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
                unitprice = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
                formUser.productcodeTB.Text = productcode
                formUser.itemdescriptionTB.Text = itemdescription
                formUser.unitpriceTB.Text = unitprice
                formUser.unitQuantityTB.Text = "1"

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In formUser.ProductAddToCartDGV.Rows
                    If Convert.ToString(row.Cells(0).Value) = formUser.productcodeTB.Text AndAlso Convert.ToString(row.Cells(2).Value) = formUser.unitpriceTB.Text Then
                        row.Cells(4).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells(3).Value * row.Cells(2).Value)
                    End If
                Next
                formUser.ProductAddToCartDGV.Rows.Add(New String() {formUser.productcodeTB.Text, formUser.itemdescriptionTB.Text, formUser.unitpriceTB.Text, formUser.unitQuantityTB.Text, formUser.unitpriceTB.Text})
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
            da.Dispose()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub addQuantity()
    If formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Scan a barcode")
    Else
        Try
            dbconnection()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM products_database WHERE Product_Code = @ProductCode;"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = sql
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text)
            End With
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter
            dt = New DataTable
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim productcode, itemdescription, unitprice As String
                Dim repeated As Boolean = False
                productcode = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
                itemdescription = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
                unitprice = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)

                formUser.productcodeTB.Text = productcode
                formUser.itemdescriptionTB.Text = itemdescription
                formUser.unitpriceTB.Text = unitprice
                formUser.unitQuantityTB.Text = "1"

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In formUser.ProductAddToCartDGV.Rows
                    If Convert.ToString(row.Cells(0).Value) = formUser.productcodeTB.Text AndAlso Convert.ToString(row.Cells(2).Value) = formUser.unitpriceTB.Text Then
                        row.Cells(3).Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells(3).Value + 1))
                        row.Cells(4).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells(3).Value * row.Cells(2).Value)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
            da.Dispose()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub minusQuantity()
    If formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Scan a barcode")
    Else
        Try
            dbconnection()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM products_database WHERE Product_Code = @ProductCode;"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = sql
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", formUser.itemproductcodeTB.Text)
            End With
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter
            dt = New DataTable
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim productcode, itemdescription, unitprice As String
                Dim repeated As Boolean = False
                productcode = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
                itemdescription = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
                unitprice = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)

                formUser.productcodeTB.Text = productcode
                formUser.itemdescriptionTB.Text = itemdescription
                formUser.unitpriceTB.Text = unitprice
                formUser.unitQuantityTB.Text = "1"

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In formUser.ProductAddToCartDGV.Rows
                    If Convert.ToString(row.Cells(0).Value) = formUser.productcodeTB.Text AndAlso Convert.ToString(row.Cells(2).Value) = formUser.unitpriceTB.Text Then
                        row.Cells(3).Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells(3).Value - 1))
                        row.Cells(4).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells(3).Value * row.Cells(2).Value)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
            da.Dispose()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

[Here is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILWqW.png)

Comment: That's totally not how datagridview was intended to be used  and I get the feeling that life would be hugely simpler if you were using datatables instead of shooing the values in and out of datagridviews

Comment: Wouldn't your user be more comfortable choosing the Item Name (Bread, Rice, etc.) rather than a number?

Comment: Is the Item Product Code the same as Product Barcode? Since you already have a Barcode for the Item, this get confusing. 2 Barcodes?

Comment: Where is the Price of the items stored in the database? Do you need the Product code for this part of the application? What is the Quantity plus and minus about? Are you keeping track of inventory here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

- Make a new project
- Rename Form1 to MainForm
- Add a DataSet type of file, called ProdDataSet. Close it id VS opens it
- Open ProdDataSet.xsd **in a text editor** and paste this over the top of the entire contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ProdDataSet" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/ProdDataSet.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/ProdDataSet.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ProdDataSet.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
      <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
        <Connections />
        <Tables />
        <Sources />
      </DataSource>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="ProdDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msprop:EnableTableAdapterManager="true" msprop:Generator_DataSetName="ProdDataSet" msprop:Generator_UserDSName="ProdDataSet">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Products" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="ProductsDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableProducts" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="Products" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="ProductsRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="ProductsRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="ProductsRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="ProductsRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="Products" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="ProductsRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="ProductsRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="ProductsRow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Id" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Id" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="IdColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Id" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="Name" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnName" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Name" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="NameColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Price" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnPrice" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Price" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="PriceColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Price" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Order" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="OrderDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableOrder" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="Order" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="OrderRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="OrderRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="OrderRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="OrderRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="Order" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="OrderRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="OrderRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="OrderRow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ProductId" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnProductId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="ProductId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="ProductIdColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="ProductId" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="Qty" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnQty" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Qty" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="QtyColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Qty" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="UnitPrice" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnUnitPrice" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="UnitPrice" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="UnitPriceColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="UnitPrice" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Total" msdata:ReadOnly="true" msdata:Expression="[Qty]*[UnitPrice]" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnTotal" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Total" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="TotalColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Total" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:Products" />
      <xs:field xpath="mstns:Id" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="Order_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:Order" />
      <xs:field xpath="mstns:ProductId" />
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

- Save it. Reopen it in Visual Studio's designer view (double click it) and arrange the tables inside a bit, save it again (it causes necessary code to be generated when you save it in the designer)
- Add a NumericUpDown control to the form and call it _prodIdNumericUpDown
- Add a Button to the form, call it _addButton. Double click it and place this code in the handler:

```
        Dim prod = _prodDataSet.Products.FindById(CInt(_prodIdNumericUpDown.Value))

        If prod Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Not a product id")
            Return
        End If


        'lookup the product in the order
        Dim orderedProduct = _prodDataSet.Order.FindByProductId(prod.Id)

        If orderedProduct Is Nothing Then
            _prodDataSet.Order.AddOrderRow(prod.Id, 1, prod.Price)
        Else
            orderedProduct.Qty += 1
        End If
```

- Place this code in the form's constructor:

```
        'put it after InitializeComponent()
        _prodDataSet.Products.AddProductsRow(1, "apples", 1.23)
        _prodDataSet.Products.AddProductsRow(2, "oranges", 2.34)
        _prodDataSet.Products.AddProductsRow(3, "pears", 3.45)
```

- Open the data sources window (View menu, other windows) and drag each of the Order and Products nodes to the form to create grids. In the tray at the bottom of the form, ensure you rename the dataset to `_prodDataSet`
- Run the program

Looks like this. Choose a product, click add, the first time you click it adds the product to the order. The second time you click it increments the Qty of the existing item - it's about 5 lines of code if you use datasets/datatables (which, imho, is one way it *should* be done):

[image]

Now all you have to do is hook things up so your database data is fed into the datatables, not datagrids. It's easy to do - open that DataSet in the designer, right click the surface and choose Add TableAdapter. Go through the wizard to connect the dataset to your mysql db. (You need [MySQL for Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/) installed to make your life easy)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying to my question. I wanna explain some things from my project. The reason I didn't gave the option to input the quantity when the system detects the same "Item Product Code" it has to add the quantity to the item in cart. Where the "Item Barcode" if repeated then it has to remove the item/ reduce the quantity from cart. I'm still new on vb. Wish I can get help. [here is the gif for the current system output](https://imgur.com/gallery/zHJ7hRy)

Comment: It's no different to what I posted; you seem to be saying that if the product is looked up by one way then you add, by another way then you remove. I only look up an item one way, and add.. You can put more code to do the lookup another way and remove

Answer (score 0):

I created a class with all the properties of the items. Having the parametrized constructor (`Sub New`) ensures that an Item has all its data. The ComboBox will call `ToString` on our class when it adds the Items. The override of ToString tells the ComboBox what to display.

```
Public Class Item

    Public Property ProductCode As Integer
    Public Property BarCode As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal
    Public Property ItemProductType As String

    Public Sub New(ProCode As Integer, BCode As String, Nm As String, Pr As Decimal, Type As String)
        ProductCode = ProCode
        BarCode = BCode
        Name = Nm
        Price = Pr
        ItemProductType = Type
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function

End Class
```

This what my form looks like.
[image]

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

The Form.Load simply calls 2 methods.

```
Public Class PointOfSale
    Private Sub PointOfSale_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillComboBox()
        BindGrid()
    End Sub
```

I made the `Items` list a Form level variable in case you need it for other methods. If it turns out that you don't, you can move it inside the `FillComboBox` method

```
Private Items As New List(Of Item)
```

This method retrieves a `DataTable` with `GetComboData`. Create a `New Item` for each row in the DataTable. Then the `Item` is added to the list of items. The ComboBox uses the list as its `DataSource`. It is significant that the entire `Item` object is stored in the ComboBox. At any point we can cast the `SelectedItem` back to its underlying type (`Item`) and access all of its properties. The ComboBox calls `ToString` on `Item` and displays the `Name` property as we coded in the Item class.

```
Private Sub FillComboBox()
    Dim dt = GetComboData()
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim It As New Item(CInt(row(0)), row(1).ToString, row(2).ToString, CDec(row(3)), row(4).ToString)
        Items.Add(It)
    Next
    ComboBox1.DataSource = Items
End Sub
```

This data access method gets data from both the item table and the products table. `productCode` is a Foreign Key in the Items table.

```
Private Function GetComboData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql = "Select 
                    items.productCode, 
                    items.barCode, 
                    items.`name`, 
                    items.price, 
                    products.productName
            From items
            Inner Join products 
            on items.productCode = products.productCode;"
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.POSConnection),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

On to the second method called from Form.Load. We create a `DataTable` that initially has no data. It does have columns with datatypes. The last column is a calculated column which will display the result of the calculation as data is added to the `DataTable`

```
Private dat As New DataTable

Private Sub BindGrid()
    With dat.Columns
        .Add("Product Code", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Product Type", GetType(String))
        .Add("Bar Code", GetType(String))
        .Add("Product Name", GetType(String))
        .Add("Price", GetType(Decimal))
        .Add("Quantity", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Total", GetType(Decimal), "Price * Quantity")
    End With
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dat
End Sub
```

Adding an item to order involves adding data to the `DataTable`. It will display in grid because the grid uses this `DataTable` as a `DataSource`. First we cast the selected item in the combo back to its underlying type (the `Item` class). Now we can access all the properties to fill in the `DataTable`. The `Quantity` is retrieved NumericUpDown instead of a text box so we don't have to check if it is a valid number. The Grand Total is calculated by looping through the rows in the DataTable grabbing the calculated value.

```
Private Sub btnAddToOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddToOrder.Click
    Dim it = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, Item)
    dat.Rows.Add({it.ProductCode, it.ItemProductType, it.BarCode, it.Name, it.Price, NumericUpDown1.Value})
    Dim Total As Decimal
    For Each row As DataRow In dat.Rows
        Total += CDec(row("Total"))
    Next
    txtGrandTotal.Text = Total.ToString
End Sub
```

End Class

This may or may not be what you are looking for but it might give you an idea of another approach.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying to my question. I wanna explain some things from my project. The reason I didn't gave the option to input the quantity when the system detects the same "Item Product Code" it has to add the quantity to the item in cart. Where the "Item Barcode" if repeated then it has to remove the item/ reduce the quantity from cart. I'm still new on vb. Wish I can get help. [here is the gif for the current system output](https://imgur.com/gallery/zHJ7hRy)

Comment: @MuthuKumar Why are you using 2 grids? Where is Quantity coming from? Why would you want the user to type in the bar code? Too easy to make a mistake.

Comment: @MuthuKumar If you want to change the quantity after the item is entered just do the edit directly in the grid. When you move off the that row in the grid, the total will recalculate. You will need to add code to an event to display the Grand Total correctly. Perhaps the DataTable.RowChanged